# Saving updated complex model to complex Entity Framework entities?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, automapper

I am using Automapper to copy the data from my data objects to my view model objects.

```
cfg.CreateMap<Customer, CustomerVM>().ReverseMap();
cfg.CreateMap<Order, OrderVM>().ReverseMap();
```

There is a navigation property between the `Order` and the `Customer`. This works fine for displaying the complex objects on my view.

```
@Html.EditorFor(a => a.Customer.AccountName)
@Html.EditorFor(a => a.Notes)
```

And the objects seem to map back properly in my post action.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult SaveOrder(OrderVM order)
{
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var order2 = AutomapperConfig.MapperConfiguration.CreateMapper().Map<OrderVM, Order>(order);
            order2.LastEditDate = DateTime.Now;
            order2.LastEditBy = HttpContext.User.Identity.Name;
            order2.CreateDate = order.CreateDate;

            using (var db = new ProofingContext())
            {                  
                db.Entry(order2).State = EntityState.Modified;
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("index");
            }
        }

        return View();
}
```

When I step thru the code in the post action the view model shows the updated data in all the related objects. But when I save the changes I only get the changes to the order saved to my DB. What do I need to do to save the changes to the related objects too?

Answer (score 0):

From this [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj592676.aspx)(*Attaching an existing but modified entity to the context* section):

> Note that if the entity being attached has references to other
>   entities that are not yet tracked, then these new entities will
>   attached to the context in the `Unchanged` state—they will not
>   automatically be made `Modified`. If you have multiple entities that
>   need to be marked `Modified` you should set the state for each of these
>   entities individually.

As an alternative, there is a [library (GraphDiff)](https://www.nuget.org/packages/RefactorThis.GraphDiff/) that allows you update the entire graph of detached entities. For more info take a look this [post](http://blog.brentmckendrick.com/introducing-graphdiff-for-entity-framework-code-first-allowing-automated-updates-of-a-graph-of-detached-entities/).In your case it would be:

```
 context.UpdateGraph(order2, map => map.OwnedEntity(x => x.Customer)
                                       .OwnedCollection(p => p.Notes));
```